# Is it possible to avoid trashing hard disk while using /tmp as a RAM device?

Tags: hard-disk, tmpfs, tmp, caching

## Origin

I need to implement some features to my GDB helper scripts but I have to stick with an older version of GDB (5.3, in this case). Since older versions lack so many features, I need to workaround the required features by redirecting some strings to a file and then `source` them.

## Problem

I don't want to trash my hard disk with intensive amount of temporary files written to `/tmp`.

## Assumption

Since my `/tmp` folder is mounted with `tmpfs`, I assume that it's actually placed on RAM and it's swapped out to swap area when filled:

```
$ mount | grep /tmp
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=524288k)
```

## Question

Can I guarantee that any small file (max 30 characters long strings) I wrote into `/tmp` (which I'll delete almost immediately) will only live in RAM in its lifetime and won't go into hard disk, even the frequency is as high as 100 writes per second?

Comment: "I don't want to trash my hard disk with intensive amount of temporary files written to `/tmp`" I don't think that's a real problem. I suggest you do some testing before assuming that that is a problem ;-) If you don't want your tmpfs to ever hit the disk, disable the swap. Problem solved.

Comment: Besides, except for special/embedded setups, it's a very bad idea to use any ram-based filesystem for `/tmp`. People create temporary files with the explicit purpose of not using up the ram, and not putting strain on the system that way, and using tmpfs for `/tmp` perversely subverts it.

Comment: If you use ramfs instead of tmpfs, files will remain in RAM and not go to disk.

Comment: Is your question mainly concerned with _security_ (leave no trace on the hard drive), or with _wear_ (keep the hard drive operational for as long as possible)?

Comment: My main goal was keeping the hard drive operational as long as possible, protecting from wear.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling your swap using a command like `swapoff --all` ([`swapoff` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/swapoff)), will guarantee `tmpfs` will never reach your disk storage.

In kernels before `6.4`, there are no other methods to force it unless you patch the kernel module.

In kernel version `6.4`, the option `noswap` was added. [Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.4/filesystems/tmpfs.html) notes:

> `noswap`: Disables swap. Remounts must respect the original settings. By default swap is enabled.

Comment: Just to be exactly on the same page: Whether we use swap or not, isn't there a guaranteed caching mechanism in the Linux kernel for small sized and short lived files?

Comment: @ceremcem randomly answering you as I stop by (and update this with more current info), the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.4/) says that tmpfs uses it's own filesystem, meaning neither the kernel filesystem (and normal file system caching caching) nor block level caching (e.g. ordering writes) would be used - so tmpfs files wouldn't be doubly in RAM (as I think you were alluding to).

Comment: @MarkLopez [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html) says it all, thank you. Please move your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.